# Copy and paste across logout/reboot?

Tags: clipboard, reboot

Is there an application or feature that allows a copy and paste across log outs or reboots?

Linux rome 4.8.0-32-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 13 14:30:16 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Check out [the list of clipboard managers in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/clipboard#List_of_clipboard_managers).  Several clipboard managers support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google for "linux persistent clipboard" gave a few sites listing several clipboard managers for Linux with various options for history management - I'm sure at least one of them will do what you want!

http://www.tecmint.com/best-clipboard-managers-for-linux/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/174051)

Comment: @Anthon Just saying “look for a clipboard manager” does answer the question, if minimally.